# How to replace the following ^ without removing the &rdquo;?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace the `^` in the following string:

```
var string = 'I\'M SORRY,&rdquo;^ mutters a strangely familiar voice.'
```

I'm doing this:

```
string.replace(/\b\^|(\.|\,|\?|\!|---|\.\.\.\s)\^|(["]|&rdquo;)\^/g, '$1</b>')
```

But I remove the `&rdquo;`:

```
I'M SORRY,</b> mutters a strangely familiar voice.
```

What I want to write is this: replace the `^` for `</b>` when it's AFTER a `"` or `&rdquo;`.

I also tried doing this:

`string.replace(/\b\^|(\.|\,|\?|\!|---|\.\.\.\s)\^|(?=(["]|&rdquo;))\^/g, '$1</b>')`

But the `^` isn't replaced:

```
I'M SORRY,&rdquo;^ mutters a strangely familiar voice.
```

What's the correct way of doing this?

Comment: You have two groups, so replace with `'$1$2</b>'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Oh, thanks that worked. Maybe post it as an answer?

Comment: Don't you just need `string.replace(/(&rdquo;|")\^/g, '$1</b>')` instead of that long regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using backreferences to keep the captured parts in the result.

Your regex has got 2 capturing groups:

```
/\b\^|([.,?!]|---|\.{3}\s)\^|("|&rdquo;)\^/g
      |------1-----------|   |----2----|
```

So, to keep both these captured parts, you need to add `$1` **and** `$2` to the replacement pattern:

```
"$1$2</b>"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BHvvtI/1)

Also, note that `["]` is equal `"` and `(\.|\,|\?|\!|---|\.\.\.\s)` is shortened to `([.,?!]|---|\.{3}\s)` (this way, you will avoid overescaping, too).

Also, note that the branches only differ in capturing groups, they both end with `\^` pattern. Thus, you may merge the branches into one:

```
/(\b|[.,?!"]|---|&rdquo;|\.{3}\s)\^/g
```

and then replace with just what you had, `"$1</b>"`.

Comment: There is no need for two capturing groups `/\b\^|([.,?!"]|---|\.{3}\s|&rdquo;)\^/g`

Comment: Right, it can be "shrunk" even further because the two branches only differ in capturing groups contents. If the content is different, then it would not be possible.

Answer (score 3):

use this:

```
string.replace(/\b\^|(\.|\,|\?|\!|---|\.\.\.\s)\^|(["]|&rdquo;)\^/g, '$2</b>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this pattern: `(?<="|&rdquo;)\^`.

It simply *looks behind* `(?<="|&rdquo;)`, to see if what preceeds current position is `"` or `&rdquo;`. If that's true, then match `^` and replace the match with `<\b>`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/F45Dz6/1)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding an extra capturing parenthesis on the whole left part.
The new regex would look like:

```
/(\b\^|(\.|\,|\?|\!|---|\.\.\.\s)\^|(["]|&rdquo;))\^/g
```

Checkout the following:

```js
var s = 'I\'M SORRY,&rdquo;^ mutters a strangely familiar voice.';

console.log('BEFORE:', s);

t = s.replace(/(\b\^|(\.|\,|\?|\!|---|\.\.\.\s)\^|(["]|&rdquo;))\^/g, '$1</b>');

console.log('AFTER:', t);
```

Hope it helped!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what are the other elements you are looking for in your `regex` but you can just look for what you want. Just `^` after `"` or `&rdquo;` and replace with `<match found> + </b>`

```js
var str = 'I\'M SORRY,&rdquo;^ mutters a strangely familiar ^voice none "of"^ the magic.'

var res = str.replace(/("|&rdquo;)\^/g,"$1</b>");

console.log(res);
```